# For an Amplify Datastore setup, is there a way to turn off AWS AppSync to just work locally?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync, datastore

I'm using Amplify Datastore with AppSync enabled.  Data syncing is working between local and cloud, but having to execute amplify push to update cloud during development can suck up a lot of time.

How can I turn off AWS AppSync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes!** DataStore can be used with or without any cloud synchronization.

#### Android

Cloud sync is enabled when you add an API plugin. To disable cloud sync, don't add `AWSApiPlugin()`:

```kotlin
Amplify.addPlugin(AWSDataStorePlugin())

// Comment out this line:
// Amplify.addPlugin(AWSApiPlugin())

Amplify.configure(applicationContext)
```

#### iOS

Sync is enabled when there is an API plugin present. To disable sync, do not add `AWSAPIPlugin()`:

```swift
let dataStorePlugin =
    AWSDataStorePlugin(modelRegistration: AmplifyModels())
try Amplify.add(plugin: dataStorePlugin)

// Comment out this line:
// try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSAPIPlugin())

try Amplify.configure()
```

#### JavaScript

The approach is slightly different. Look for any API configurations in the `aws-exports.js` file, and remove them. Specifically, you should remove any config entries with `aws_appsync_*` in the prefix:

```json
const awsmobile = {
    // ...
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://yourid.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    "aws_appsync_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll give this a try.  On a perhaps different but related tangent, while app sync is turned on, is it possible to specify certain queries to read from local data?

Comment: @Chuender All DataStore queries are against the local data. The Apollo client lets you select between fetching from the server or a local cache. But DataStore always fetches local data.

Comment: After commenting out the AppSync configurations in aws-exports.js, I'm getting the following warnings:  [WARN] 32:13.74 DataStore - Data won't be synchronized. No GraphQL endpoint configured. Did you forget `Amplify.configure(awsconfig)`?  Anything else I need to disable?

Comment: That output indicates the behavior you were hoping for. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Was thinking if there was something else I can disable to not get the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look on the [Full offline option using AWS DataStore and then allow an optional activation for the the cloud sync features in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872577/full-offline-option-using-aws-datastore-and-then-allow-an-optional-activation-fo)

Seems like `DataStore` mind set is offline first with API available in AWS, so there is no option to not create the API in the AWS while performing `amplify push`.

Answer (score 1):

The normal solution to working offline during development is to not run `amplify push` during project setup. You can run your app locally and everything works normally, but there is no attempt to sync to the cloud. When you change your schema you run `amplify codegen models` and all the models are updated locally.

When you are finally ready to deploy to the cloud and start running in online/offline mode you run `amplify push` to provision all the cloud resources. Even after this you can still run local only by using the browser dev tools to disable the network connection.

I don't know how to set the project back to a pre `amplify push` state, but I would like the answer. I'm sure it is a setting somewhere in the amplify configuration in the project.